# Termux Errors When Running Executables

Tags: linux, rust, termux

I am learning rust and cpp using Termux, I had no problem compiling then, but when I do `./main` to run the complied code, and it always say this:

```
bash: ./main: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you running this on Android?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yessir

Comment: Notice that SD card is typically mounted with `noexec` option. Try to copy your binary to another device, for example `/data/local/tmp`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk but that executable is in `/storage/emulated/0`

Comment: and that's the problem, see output of `mount`: `/data/media on /storage/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,reserved=20MB)`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to execute the binary file in `/storage/emulated/0/` termux doesn't have permissions to execute but you can compile in that directory .
In order to execute, simply copy the file to `~/` by executing the command in termux `cp <your file> ~/`
and then you can execute it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).